# Ongoing notification on wear os watchface

Tags: notifications, wear-os, watchface

I have an app that has an ongoing notification.

Is there any way to present that specific notification on the wear os smartwatch watchface or in any other way?

Comment: Is "app" a mobile app, or is this running on the wear device?

Comment: By app I meant mobile app running on the phone

Answer (score 0):

For Media like Music/Podcast it will just happen.

For other types of apps, you could write a tiny companion app that starts the ongoing activity on the device.  Use the data layer to react to the mobile app changing state and writing its new state over the data layer.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/ongoing-activity

Also

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/ongoing-activity#0